# Multiple select inputs in table header with unique models

Tags: vue.js

I am receiving data from the backend that takes the following format

```
[ 
    [ 
        [ "123", "21/11/2013", "Data", "Data" ], 
        [ "234", "22/11/2013", "Data", "Data" ], 
        [ "345", "12/09/2018", "Data", "Data" ], 
    ], 
    [ 
        [ "123", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data" ], 
        [ "234", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data" ], 
        [ "345", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data" ] 
    ] 
]
```

Each fileData represents a table, so in the above example it should produce two tables.  The data inside contains a tables rows, so each table above has two rows.
In order to achieve this I am doing something like the following.

```
<table class="table" v-for="(file, index) in fileData" :key="index">
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row, index2) in file":key="index2">
          <td v-for="(data, index3) in row" :key="index3">
            {{ data }}
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This all seems to work fine.  However, the data I am using does not have headers, but I need to prodive a header for each column that contains a select.  As such I have added the following

```
<table class="table" v-for="(file, index) in fileData" :key="index">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th scope="col" v-for="(col, index2) in file[index]" :key="index2">
             <b-form-select v-model="options.value" :options="options"></b-form-select>
           </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Once again this seems to work.  My problem is that I want the user to define what a column represents, using the select.  At the moment, if I select something, they all change.

I have produced this Fiddle as an example https://jsfiddle.net/mhyv62bt/1/

How can I make the selects independent, and is it also possible to remove an option once selected?

Thanks

This seems to produce the correct number of header columns for each table.

**Update**
I have a slightly different setup so trying to fit it in with my project.  As such, I created the file THeadSelect.vue

```
<template id="theadselect">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th
      v-for="(i,index) in this.length_"
      :key="index"
    >
      <select
        v-model="headers[index]">
        <option disabled value="">
          Please select one
        </option>

        <option
          v-if="headers[index]"
          selected
        >
          {{headers[index]}}
        </option>
        <option
          v-for="option in filteredOptions"
          :key="option"
        >
          {{option}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.$emit('update:headers',
      this.headers
        .concat(Array.from({ length: this.length_ }, _ => ''))
        .slice()
    )
  },
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    length: Number,
    headers: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    length_: {
      get () {
        return this.length || this.options.length
      },
      set (l) {
        this.$emit('update:length', l)
      }
    },
    filteredOptions () {
      return this.options.filter(
        option => !this.headers.includes(option)
      )
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am then trying to use this within my page

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form
      novalidate
      @submit.stop.prevent=""
    >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <table class="table table-bordered" v-for="(file, index) in fileData" :key="index">
            <thead
              is="THeadSelect"
              :options="['option1', 'option2', 'option3']"
              :headers.sync="headers"
            ></thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(row, index2) in file" :key="index2">
              <td v-for="(data, index3) in row" :key="index3">
                {{ data }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </b-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { THeadSelect } from '@/components/common/THeadSelect'

export default {
  components: {
    THeadSelect
  },
  computed: {
    fileData () {
      return this.$store.getters.fileData
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [],
      length: 10,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It is a bit messed up though.  Only 3 selects are being displayed for each table.  Additionally, if I select an option in table 1, it selects the same option in table 2.  If you check out my original fiddle you can see the initial data I am trying to work with, so there will always be two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can make this a component

### The header:

Possible usage:

```
<thead
  is="THeadSelect"
  :options="header_row"
  :length="length /*defaults to options.length*/"
  :headers.sync="headers"
></thead>
```

*The ComponentOptions*

```
//*.js
const THeadSelect = {
  template: "#theadselect",
  mounted(){
    // make sure headers is populated
    this.$emit("update:headers",
     this.headers
     .concat(Array.from({length:this.length_}, _=>""))
     .slice()
    )
  },
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    length: Number,
    headers: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed:{
    length_:{
      get(){
        return this.length || this.options.length
      },
      set(l){
        this.$emit("update:length",l)
      }
    },
    filteredOptions(){
      return this.options.filter(
        option => !this.headers.includes(option)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

*The template*

```
// *.html 
<template id="theadselect">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th
        v-for="(i,index) in length_"
        :key="index"
      >
        <select 
          v-model="headers[index]">
          <option disabled value="">
            Please select one
          </option>

          <option
            v-if="headers[index]"
            selected
          >
            {{headers[index]}}
          </option>
          <option
           v-for="option in filteredOptions"
           :key="option"
          >
            {{option}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</template>
```

### Example

```js
const THeadSelect = {
  template: "#theadselect",
  mounted(){
    // make sure headers is populated
    this.$emit("update:headers",
     this.headers
     .concat(Array.from({length:this.length_}, _=>""))
     .slice()
    )
  },
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    length: Number,
    headers: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed:{
    length_:{
      get(){
        return this.length || this.options.length
      },
      set(l){
        this.$emit("update:length",l)
      }
    },
    filteredOptions(){
      return this.options.filter(
        option => !this.headers.includes(option)
      )
    }
  }
}

new Vue({

  components: {THeadSelect},
  data(){
    return {
      headers: [],
      length: 10
    }
  },
  template: "#root"
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template id="theadselect">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th
        v-for="(i,index) in length_"
        :key="index"
      >
        <select 
          v-model="headers[index]">
          <option value="">
            Please select one
          </option>
          <option
            v-if="headers[index]"
            selected
          >
            {{headers[index]}}
          </option>
          <option
           v-for="option in filteredOptions"
           :key="option"
          >
            {{option}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</template>

<template id="root">
  <div>
  <table>
    <caption>Sample usage with select</caption>
    <thead 
      is="THeadSelect"
      :options="['option1', 'option2', 'option3']"
      :headers.sync="headers"
    ></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td
          v-for="(prop, index) in headers"
          :key="prop+index"
        >
          {{ prop || '?'}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</template>
<table id="app"></table>
```

For the body one can think about the value of the headers array. Maybe put array indeces or object properties instead of currently option values

### So for multiple tables one can think about:

```html
<template id="table">
  <table

    v-for="(table, index) in tables"
    :key="'table-'+index"
    is="TableSelect"
    :headers="table[0]"
    :rows="table.slice(1)"
  >
  </table>
</template>
```

And for TableSelect:

```js
const TableSelect = {
  props: ["headers", "rows"],
  template: "#table-select",
  data(){
    return {
      selectedHeaders: []
    }
  },
  computed(){
    mappedRows(){
      return this.rows
      .map(row=> row.map(
        (cell, index) => ({[headers[index]]: cell})
      ).reduce((obj, val) => Object.assign(obj, val))
    )}
  }
}
```

```html
<template id="table-select">
  <table>
    <thead
      is="THeadSelect"
      :options="headers"
      :headers.sync="selectedHeaders"
    ></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr
        v-for="(row, index) in mappedRows"
        :key="'row-'+index"
      >
        <td
          v-for="cell in selectedHeaders"
          :key="cell+index"
        >
          {{cell && row[cell || ""]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

*there are errors in above code but due to lazyness and missing linter on so i will let it be - as it provides the basic idea.*

---

### And a running example on codesandbox:

https://lbm8l.csb.app/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just going through it to make sure I fully understand it.  One question, you have a delete col button which I don't really need.  What I was trying to do is this.  You have provided Option 1 and Option 2.  If one of the selects takes one of these options, I want to remove it from the other selects.  Would something like this be possible?

Comment: I made an update to my original post.  Trying to fit in with current setup, and the data I already have, seem to be causing issues.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id='app'>
<table class="table table-bordered" v-for="(file, index) in fileData" :key="index">
    <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" v-for="(col, index2) in file[index]" :key="index2+index">
      <b-form-select v-model="selectedValue[index+index2]" :options="options">
        <template v-slot:first>
          <b-form-select-option :value="null" disabled>Ignore</b-form-select-option>
        </template>
      </b-form-select>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(row, index2) in file" :key="index2">
    <td v-for="(data, index3) in row" :key="index3">
      {{ data }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
data: {
selectedValue: [],
mappedColumns: [],
selected: null,
options: [{
    value: '1',
    text: 'Option 1'
  },
  {
    value: '2',
    text: 'Option 2'
  },
  {
    value: '3',
    text: 'Option 3'
  }
],
```

You are using a single value in `v-model` for all the dropdowns. so, once you change a single dropdown. All of them gets changed.

Try the above solution, where I declared a new array in `data` which is `selectedValue`
You can keep the data of which dropdown is selected in this array

Answer (score 2):

Use `v-on:change` and a function instead of `v-model`  Here is the solution for individual selection

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    mappedColumns: [],
    selected: null,
    options: [{
        value: '1',
        text: 'Option 1'
      },
      {
        value: '2',
        text: 'Option 2'
      },
      {
        value: '3',
        text: 'Option 3'
      }
    ],
    fileData: [
      [
        ["123", "21/11/2013", "Data", "Data"],
        ["234", "22/11/2013", "Data", "Data"],
        ["345", "12/09/2018", "Data", "Data"],
      ],
      [
        ["123", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data",
          "Data"
        ],
        ["234", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data",
          "Data"
        ],
        ["345", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data",
          "Data"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getSelectedItem(a, b, c) {
      console.log(a, b, c);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tether@1.4.7/dist/css/tether.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tether@1.4.7/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #app {
      padding: 20px;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='app'>
    <table class="table table-bordered" v-for="(file, index) in fileData" :key="index">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" v-for="(col, index2) in file[index]" :key="index2">
            <b-form-select v-on:change="getSelectedItem($event,index,index2)" :options="options">
              <template v-slot:first>
                                <b-form-select-option :value="null" disabled>Ignore</b-form-select-option>
                            </template>
            </b-form-select>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row, index2) in file" :key="index2">
          <td v-for="(data, index3) in row" :key="index3">
            {{ data }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="table.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```